# How to add error message for DropDown List in MVC Project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I use ajax to take list of items from JSON for my DropDown List(Because i Have Cascade DropDown). Now i need to add error message if is nothing choiced for "Pravec":

Dropdown code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pravec", new   SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), "Изберете Релација",  new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" })
```

and ajax code:

```
 $(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/relacii/getPravecList",
            datatype: "Json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    $('#Pravec').append('<option value="' + value.r1ID + '">' + value.relIme + '</option>');
                });

            }
        });

         $('#Pravec').change(function () {

             $('#DatumRID').empty();

             service_id = $('select[name=\'Pravec\']').val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/relacii/getRelaciiList1?rID=" + service_id,
                datatype: "Json",
                data: { relacijaID: $('#Pravec').val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                         $('#DatumRID').append('<option value="' + value.relID + '">' + value.DatumForDisplay + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a default option like

```
 $('#Pravec').append('<option value="-1">'--------Please Select One-------'</option>');
```

before append the result from the ajaxcall. Then you can check the value at the change event of the first dropdown(i.e #Pravec).

The whole code may be like bellow

```
     $(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/relacii/getPravecList",
                datatype: "Json",
                success: function (data) {
                $('#Pravec').append('<option value="-1">'--------Please Select One-------'</option>');
                    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                        $('#Pravec').append('<option value="' + value.r1ID + '">' + value.relIme + '</option>');
                    });

                }
            });

             $('#Pravec').change(function () {

                 $('#DatumRID').empty();

                 service_id = $('select[name=\'Pravec\']').val();
                  if (service_id=="-1") {
                       alert("please select");
                  }
            else {
                  $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/relacii/getRelaciiList1?rID=" + service_id,
                    datatype: "Json",
                    data: { relacijaID: $('#Pravec').val() },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                             $('#DatumRID').append('<option value="' + value.relID + '">' + value.DatumForDisplay + '</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
               }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I doed it, but not work again, not show error message. :(

Comment: At line 
service_id = $('select[name=\'Pravec\']').val();  if you get "-1" then it should show the message. You can try

service_id = $(this).val();